# How to create empty item in list?

Tags: lists, enumerate

So far my list looks like this:

[image]

I want to get rid of "item 1" and have a blank there. Except when I delete "item 1" my sublist moves up like so:

[image]

How can I format my list so that I can have a blank instead of "item 1"?

My latex code:

```
\begin{enumerate}    

\item item 1

  \begin{enumerate}
    \item sub list 1
    \item sub list 2
    \item sub list 3

  \end{enumerate}

\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: related: [Moving an enumerate up](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/126258/579)

Comment: How about using \hfill?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

You only need to remove spaces before nested enumerate.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item%
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item sub list 1
    \item sub list 2
    \item sub list 3
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** Mico noted , that I misunderstand the question :-( His and Boris solution is than correct, not mine. As an alternative to `\quad` you can use invisible character `~`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[a4paper,showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item ~
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item sub list 1
  \item sub list 2
  \item sub list 3
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
    \end{document}
```

which gives what you like to obtain:

[image]

Comment: I think the OP wants to preserve the empty line after "1.". Your answer currently does not.

Comment: Probably, then I misunderstand the question. I read it again, you have right!

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item \leavevmode
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item sub list 1
  \item sub list 2
  \item sub list 3
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
```

(see The TeXbook for the discussion of `\leavevmode` for switching from the 'vertical mode')

[image]

Comment: Hmmm.  Please post the complete mwe

Comment: I'd recommend `\mbox{}` instead. It's true that `\leavevmode` is useful in some cases, but it should not land in the body of the document if possible.  Explicitly, I mean, not from within a macro.

Answer (score 4):

Just replace `item \#1` with `\quad`. :-)

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}    
\item \quad
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item sub list 1
    \item sub list 2
    \item sub list 3
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstand the question. See edit of my answer. I erase my previous comment!